# Azure DevOps Automated tests and Configuration

Tags: azure-devops, configuration, automated-tests, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there any relationship between a configuration and an automated test? Example if I had a Test to click on a button on a webpage (automated) and wanted to run tests on Edge and Chrome.

If I then setup 2 configurations for each Browser and associate them to the test suite. (I see 2 test cases one each for each configuration). When I select run automated test from the UI, I don't see the configuration passed into the Release pipeline details (used REST API to check)?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the relationship on test runs page. Here are my steps:

1.Run automated test from the UI:
[image]
2. Click view test run button:

[image]

3.You can see the find the outcome by configuration on test runs page:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Walter. 

It's still not clear to me how the configuration was chosen? Let's say you have a Agent Pool with one agent demand set to Browser = Chrome and another agent demand set to Browser = Firefox. Will the configuration map to the demands on the agents in the machine pool and run tests on those agents?

Or is the configuration detail passed into the test execution context and the test can read the configuration option and launch the correct browser?

Comment: @loganwol You need to configure two different releases or stages with different configurations. Then, choose the corresponding stage when running automated test in Test Plan. According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#q-what-happens-if-i-select-multiple-configurations-for-the-same-test):Currently, the on-demand workflow is not configuration-aware. In future releases, we plan to pass configuration context to the test method and report the appropriate results.

Comment: Please also refer to this document about [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Walter, I have read that documentation before. It does not answer my question of the configurations mapping to Agents in a machine pool in the pipeline?

Comment: Did some digging around with Postman on the Release using the REST API's and don't see anything that's passed on from the test plan to the release pipeline request. Very disappointing.

Comment: How does Multi-configuration work? The help messages says the configuration get's passed in, but how is it getting passed in? I don't see anything in the REST api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.